# how to write nested python package

Tags: python, import, module, nested, package

I wrote a program which uses nested packages, but i think it's not an "official" way.

I storing the common objects and variables in the `__init__` and i want to reach those from the pack' modules (one.py, two.py) and the top-level script too (main.py). If i'm nesting my packs inside another pack, then i have to rewrite the imports manually, for example from `import pack` to `import nested.pack`.

I tried `from . import *` (`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'one'`) and the `import ..pack` (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`) but none of them worked. Nor this:

```
import importlib
pack = importlib.import_module( __package__ )
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pack.one
  File "pack\one.py", line 4, in <module>
    pack = importlib.import_module( __package__ )
  File "python32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 117, in import_module
    if name.startswith('.'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I think i found a good solution for the `import` statements to be 'depth independent', but it maybe not a common way.

```
_______________________________ DIRECTORY TREE _______________________________

main.py
pack/
  __init__.py
  one.py
  subpack/
    __init__.py
    two.py

___________________________________ FILES ____________________________________

__ MAIN.PY ____________________________

  import pack
  import pack.one
  import pack.subpack
  import pack.subpack.two

  print( '__ MAIN.PY ____________________________' )

  print( 'PACK.VAR', pack.var )
  print( 'SUBPACK.VAR', pack.subpack.var )

  pack.one.fnc()
  pack.subpack.two.fnc()

__ PACK/__INIT__.PY ___________________

  import sys

  __all__ = [ 'one' ]

  var = sys.modules[ __name__ ]

__ PACK/ONE.PY ________________________

  import sys
  pack = __import__( '.'.join( __name__ .split( '.' )[0:-1] ) )

  def fnc():
    print( '__ ONE.PY _____________________________' )
    print( sys.modules[ __name__ ] )
    print( 'PACK.VAR', pack.var )

__ PACK/SUBPACK/__INIT__.PY ___________

  import sys

  __all__ = [ 'two' ]

  var = sys.modules[ __name__ ]

__ PACK/SUBPACK/TWO.PY ________________

  import sys
  subpack = __import__( '.'.join( __name__ .split( '.' )[0:-1] ) )

  def fnc():
    print( '__ TWO.PY _____________________________' )
    print( sys.modules[ __name__ ] )
    print( 'SUBPACK.VAR', subpack.var )

___________________________________ OUTPUT ___________________________________

__ MAIN.PY ____________________________
PACK.VAR &lt;module 'pack' from 'e:\laci\0_uj\korrekcio\tmp\pack\__init__.py'&gt;
__ ONE.PY _____________________________
&lt;module 'pack.one' from 'e:\laci\0_uj\korrekcio\tmp\pack\one.py'&gt;
SUBPACK.VAR &lt;module 'pack' from 'e:\laci\0_uj\korrekcio\tmp\pack\__init__.py'&gt;
SUBPACK.VAR &lt;module 'pack.subpack' from 'e:\laci\0_uj\korrekcio\tmp\pack\subpack\__init__.py'&gt;
__ TWO.PY _____________________________
&lt;module 'pack.subpack.two' from 'e:\laci\0_uj\korrekcio\tmp\pack\subpack\two.py'&gt;
SUBPACK.VAR &lt;module 'pack' from 'e:\laci\0_uj\korrekcio\tmp\pack\__init__.py'&gt;
```

What is the good solution for making "depth independent" package `__init__.py` import?

I tried the codes above on Windows 7 with Python 3.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `import` statements relative to the **main** execution file. For instance, if you `main.py` file is your program starting point, inside package `one` you can write:

```
import pack
```

without any problem.

Comment: It works but i like to nest it again (make another dir above it), then i have to rewrite the import statements:
"If i'm nesting my packs inside another pack, then i have to rewrite the imports manually, for example from import pack to import nested.pack."

Comment: You can nest it any times you want, just try to keep the entry point module (main.py) on top of the entire structure. That's the best way to do something like you want. If you aren't programming and application but a package, use the "main.py" analogy and write `import` statements relative to the top package.

Comment: How can i do relative imports to the 'main.py'? If i'm inserting a level on the top of the directory tree, for example a dir called 'nested', then how can i make a relative import statement? `import pack` have to be `import nested.pack` independently from the location of the `main.py`, or i'm wrong?